# Trying to push a string into an array returned from another function

Tags: javascript

Hey I'm pretty new to coding. I've tried looking around for how to do this but am at a loss.

Below are the two functions, which are in an object.

```
listPeople: function () {
    let array = []
    return array;
    // returns an array of all people for whom tasks exist
},
add: function ( name, task ) {
    return this.listPeople().push( name )
},
```

If I run this, the add function returns 1. and will return 2 if I push two things in, and so on. What's going on here, how do i push the name variable from add into the array in listpeople?? The name variable is 'zeke' by the way.

Sorry in advance if this doesn't make sense :D

Comment: `if this doesn't make sense` very true, It doesn't make sense... Please be clear and specific what exactly do you want and You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: Every time you call `listPeople`, you’re creating a new array, which then goes nowhere because it isn’t saved anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

It should probably look more like this. Create an `arr` property, and push objects into it from `add`. You can then return that list from `listPeople`.

```js
const obj = {
  arr: [],
  listPeople: function() {
    return this.arr;
  },
  add: function(name, task) {
    return this.arr.push({ [name]: task });
  }
}

obj.add('bob', 'Shopping');
obj.add('Betty', 'Singing');
console.log(obj.listPeople());
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening in your code is that the `add` function is returning the result of the [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method (the new length of the array).

If your intent is to actually return the array, you should modify the `add` method as follows:

```js
add: function ( name, task ) {
    var people = this.listPeople();
    people.push(name);
    return people;
},
```

Additionally, while changing `listPeople` to an array *property* instead of a *method* may work better on a shallow level, I don't know what you may have planned to implement into the `listPeople` method. And it may only confuse/complicate things as far as answering the question you have asked.